# How to get automigrate to work with SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, loopbackjs

I can't get automigrate and autoupdate to work.

I created my project, datasource and model. All looks good, but I can't get automigrate to work. If I go to my SQL Server and create the table/schema then all the GET/POST methods work fine.

I went to the server/boot directory. there are currently two files in there authentication and root.

I created a new file called automigrate.js

```
'use strict';

 module.exports = function (app) {
   app.dataSources.mysql.automigrate();
   console.log("Performed automigration.");
}
```

When I run it I get an error :

> C:\Users\ajmal\loopback\telematics\server\server.js:31 if (err) throw err; ^
>
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'automigrate' of undefined
>
> at Object.module.exports [as func] (C:\Users\ajmal\loopback\telematics\server\boot\automigrate.js:9:26)
>   at C:\Users\ajmal\loopback\telematics\node_modules\loopback-boot\lib\executor.js:316:22

Comment: are you sure that your datasource is called `mysql`? Check your file `datasources.json` and make sure that you're using exactly the same datasource name

Comment: This was the issue.  I was using the connector parameter as the name instead of name from my datasourses.json.   Tx

Answer (score 1):

You can use [grunt-loopback-auto](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-loopback-auto) module or build your own by following the document at https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Creating-a-database-schema-from-models.html#auto-update

Notes:

- `automigrate` will drop and re-create the tables. Therefore, **data will be lost**. It's terrible on production.
- `autoupdate` calculates the difference between the LoopBack model and the database table definition and alters the table accordingly.

So, we should use `autoupdate` in almost cases.